# how do you download a .png onto your windows form?

Tags: vb.net

how do i go to a specified URL, grab a png image, and drop it onto my windows form in my vb.net windows application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply put a WebBrowser control on your windows form and point it to the specified URL.

Answer (score 2):

Use a picture box as suggested before. But i would suggest you to use the WebClient-Class:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadFile("URL goes here", "Local file path goes here");
```

There is also a "DownloadFileAsync" method with events.

Update: 
The PictureBox class supports direct download via:

```
pictureBox.Load("http://yourdomain.net/Image.jpg");
```

Comment: ...and how would you display it on the form?

Comment: As stated above. Use the PictureBox. You can load a local image into the PictureBox by calling pictureBox1.Load(@"C:\Image.jpg") for example. BTW. You can also provide an url so the step of downloading the image first is not necessarily needed. Sample: pictureBox1.Load("http://www.cwcity.de/community/group/pics/view/165_grp_vw.jpg");

Answer (score 1):

I would put a picture control on the form then download the picture into a Picture object using HttpWebRequest. Then set the .picture attribute of the picture control box. I would write the code to do it but I'm a bit rusty with .net stuff.